# viewDidLoad in NSViewController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

On the iPhone I use `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` to run code to set up the view.

How can I do that with `NSViewController`?

I've tried `loadView` but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As of OS X 10.10, `viewDidLoad` is available and supported on `NSViewController`.

Prior to that, you had to go by this nugget in Snow Leopards' [release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKitOlderNotes.html):

> **Advice for People who Are Looking for -viewWillLoad and -viewDidLoad Methods in NSViewController**
>
> Even though NSWindowController has -windowWillLoad and -windowDidLoad methods for you to override the NSViewController class introduced in Mac OS 10.5 does not have corresponding -viewWillLoad and -viewDidLoad methods. You can override -[NSViewController loadView] to customize what happens immediately before or immediately after nib loading done by a view controller.

Comment: I have asked it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492485/when-programming-for-mac-os-x-is-there-an-equivalent-to-viewdidload but might as well ask you too: 
I read this in the docs and tried to play around with loadView but still i am not able to understand how it helps in doing something "immediately after nib loading". I have an NSTabView in the xib file which is connected properly but still it is always 0x0 when i keep a breakpoint in loadView.

Comment: -1; Obsolete!  The linked article no-longer discusses this. :(

Comment: I think *[viewController loadView]* is not a capable method for replacing viewDidLoad. Because this method will be called by the system every time *[viewController view]* is called. So this method can be called multiple times in once application have running

Comment: @arufian you would be wrong. `-loadView` only gets called when `-view` actually needs to load the view. If it's already been loaded, it does not call through to `-loadView`

Comment: @MikeAbdullah thanks... hmm, actually I did experiments about using `-view`,  and after I debugged the program because it took too long load times, I found that `-loadView` is being called again and again and again ... :(

Comment: @arufian maybe you forgot to hook up the `view` outlet?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174952/backward-compatibility-of-xcode-osx/30196972#30196972

Answer (score 49):

I figured it out within minutes of posting my comment. Adding my finding as an answer because it is an example which is missing in the docs. The below code will give you the viewDidLoad method that you want. Its so easy in a way that i wonder why Apple has not implemented it yet in OS X.

```
- (void)viewWillLoad {
    if([NSViewController instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(viewWillLoad)]) {
        [super viewWillLoad];
    }

    ...
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if([NSViewController instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(viewWillLoad)]) {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }
}

- (void)loadView {
    BOOL ownImp = ![NSViewController instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(viewWillLoad)];

    if(ownImp) {
        [self viewWillLoad];
    }

    [super loadView];

    if(ownImp) {
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
}
```

Original source: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/195802-garbage-collection-leaks-and-drains.html

Comment: One possible danger with this is that Apple could add `-viewWillLoad` and `-viewDidLoad` methods to `NSViewController` one day. If so, your override of those methods would be called twice.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution!  I had been searching for weeks for this.

Comment: @Mike... Your concern is valid and now with 10.7 Lion being more like iOS, i think it may just make it in Lion itself. I will be keeping a watch on it so no worries for me but yes, having the same function names can cause trouble otherwise.

Comment: While this is a great example of how to replicate the viewDidLoad functionality on OS X, I'm more concerned with finding the "proper" way of doing this when doing Cocoa desktop development.

What is the correct procedure for doing things that you would normally do in viewDidLoad on iOS (like setting up your views after they're loaded from the nib) when developing for OS X?

Comment: This is the most "proper" way i could get to in replicating iOS's viewDidLoad on Mac. I have moved back to iOS development since then.

Comment: The danger pointed out in the comment above re: Apple introducing ```-viewWillLoad```, ```-viewDidLoad``` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422839/viewdidload-in-nsviewcontroller/24098857#comment5820794_5090825) has now come true: as of 10.10, these methods exist in NSViewController.

Comment: Edited in some code to support OS X Yosemite. If the system implements `viewWillLoad`/`viewDidLoad`, use the system implementation, otherwise - use the user's.

Comment: Hello , Thank you very much for this great code share, however I want to add 1 note : When you will call viewDidLoad it won't go through the NSRunLoop which means the view will not have Bounds because it is not really loaded yet... I think you should go through the run loop -> I want to figure the best way for this, maybe you can help ?

Comment: [super viewDidLoad]; this line give error in my case base sdk and deployment target = 10.9 in my case.

Answer (score 9):

As of OSX 10.10 (Yosemite), there is now a `-viewDidLoad`, `-viewWillAppear`, `-viewDidAppear`, `-viewWillDisappear` in `NSViewController`. See [WWDC 2014 - Storyboards and Controllers on OS X session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) for more info, to find out when each of them gets called, etc.

Here's the relevant bit from the 10.10 header docs about `-viewDidLoad:`

> Called after the view has been loaded. For view controllers created in
>   code, this is after -loadView. For view controllers unarchived from a
>   nib, this is after the view is set. Default does nothing.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_10);
```

Comment: I can confirm this..  as of Xcode6-B4 the Apple-provided boilerplate for an `NSVewController` subclass includes `- (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad]; // Do view setup here. }`!

Answer (score 5):

why don't you try this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    //setup code
    NSLog(@"hello there");
}
```

Comment: I tend to avoid doing things in `awakeFromNib`, as it can sometimes be called more than once. For example calling `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:` and passing self as the owner will cause `awakeFromNib` to be called. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html.

Comment: kyle i face same problem, awakeFromNib called multiple time due to makeViewWithIdentifier:owner

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in 10.10, viewDidLoad is now in NSViewController.

Answer (score -5):

hmm actually I would also do this...

```
- (void)viewWillLoad {

    if (! bool_viewwillload) {

        // execute the code
        bool_viewwillload = true;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if (! bool_viewdidload) {

        // execute the code
        bool_viewdidload = true;
    }
}
```

and then just make the load view like this

```
- (void)loadView {

    [self viewWillLoad];

    [super loadView];

    [self viewDidLoad];
}
```