# When programming for Mac OS X, is there an equivalent to viewDidLoad?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [viewDidLoad in NSViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422839/viewdidload-in-nsviewcontroller)

I started development on iOS apps and am now moving to Mac OS X apps. I was wondering if there's an equivalent method in Mac OS X that is like iOS's viewDidLoad to run code after a View Controller launches.

Thank you!

Comment: If this question no longer requires additional answers, please mark the appropriate post as an answer.

Comment: try 
- (void) awakeFromNib {}

Answer (score 9):

From the [Apple Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html):

> Advice for People who Are Looking for
>   -viewWillLoad and -viewDidLoad Methods in NSViewController
>
> Even though NSWindowController has
>   -windowWillLoad and -windowDidLoad methods for you to override the
>   NSViewController class introduced in
>   Mac OS 10.5 does not have
>   corresponding -viewWillLoad and
>   -viewDidLoad methods. You can override -[NSViewController loadView] to customize what happens immediately
>   before or immediately after nib
>   loading done by a view controller.

Comment: I read this in the docs and tried to play around with loadView but still i am not able to understand how it helps in doing something "immediately after nib loading". I have an NSTabView in the xib file which is connected properly but still it is always 0x0 when i keep a breakpoint in loadView.

Comment: Never mind, i figured it out. Added my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422839/viewdidload-in-nsviewcontroller/5090825#5090825.