# IBOutlets Not Setting in NSViewController

Tags: xcode, cocoa, null, iboutlet, automatic-ref-counting

So I've got an NSViewController (MyVC) set up like so:

```
//MyVC.h
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *input;
...

//MyVC.m
...
@synthesize input;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithNibName: @"MyVC" bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]];
    NSLog(@"%@", input); //prints (null) always
    return self;
}

- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    NSLog(@"%@", input); //still (null)
}
...

//MyVC.xib

Custom View       [Referencing Outlet:    File's Owner.view]
    Text Field    [Referencing Outlet:    File's Owner.input]
```

Now, when I load this NSViewController (by way of `MyVC *vc = [[MyVC alloc] init];`) and load it into a window, I see the Text Field appropriately. However, as the above paste (and several BAD_ACCESSes) would suggest, `vc.input` is never properly pointing to the Text Field.

*Notes:*

- This project is running ARC.
- This is not a simplification or generalization. I've run this exact code to no avail.
- All IBOutlets are definitely set up appropriately.

Comment: Do you try no NSLog in `viewDidLoad`? In `init` it will be always be NULL. In `loadView` I don't remember.

Comment: NSViewController (note, not UIViewController) does not have -viewDidLoad. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492485/when-programming-for-mac-os-x-is-there-an-equivalent-to-viewdidload)

Comment: Where’s the actual `IBOutlet` declaration?

Comment: Could the property and ivar be different, and the IBOutlet is setting the wrong one?  What happens if you log `self.input` in `loadView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was a combination of things.

One of my revisions was missing the IBOutlet tag, and none of them were retaining references to the ViewController at runtime.