# Xcode, Custom view - zero frame/bounds

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, view, interface-builder

In my app, I need to have a `splitView` and to be able to insert my own views to the panes.

To that end, in the Interface builder i have created a `SplitView` with two dividers (three panes), and added the "Custom Views" that are in those three panes as `IBOutlets` to my corresponding view controller. However, when I query the `IBOutlets` for their frame/bounds sizes, they are all 0.00000.

Why do the custom views I created in Xcode have 0 size? How can I fix that?

UPD: the code to query the frame/bounds of the panes:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.logList = [[LogListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:LOGLISTXIB bundle:nil];
        [self logARect:self.leftPane.bounds withName:@"LeftPane bounds"];
        [self logARect:self.leftPane.frame withName:@"LeftPane Frame"];
    }
}
- (void) logARect:(NSRect) theFrame withName:(NSString *)name {
    NSLog(@"%@ frame: %lf, %lf, %lf, %lf", name, theFrame.origin.x, theFrame.origin.y, theFrame.size.width, theFrame.size.height);
}
```

**UPD2** At the same time, when I access the panes by `self.view.subviews[0]`, i get the correct size.

Comment: can you show the code you are using to query the sizes and bounds of these custom views?

Comment: @AdamRichardson I have added the relevant code as an update to my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the initializer is not the place to query the size of views, or so it seems. When I check the sizes of views in the `-awakeFromNib` method, they are correct. It seems logical.

Answer (score 1):

The views are probably not laid out yet when you try to get the positions. The [viewDidLoad in NSViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422839/viewdidload-in-nsviewcontroller) question points out that `loadView` should be used to modify the view's layout. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5090825/768935) in the same question shows a trick to make your Cocoa code similar to the Cocoa-touch one.

Comment: It is Cocoa, now I have added the corresponding tag. As far as I know there is no corresponding method in Cocoa.

Comment: Not yet. But I am now just doing all the set-up programmatically instead of wiring it up in IB. It serves my purpose, but it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: Are you sure the `leftPane` is wired up correctly? Did you check if it is not null or something unexpected? Can you share some code? Does it have the correct size in a later time in the execution?

Comment: Yes, I did check all that. You can find the answer I have found as a reply to my own question. Thanks for your help anyway )

Comment: Well, then in fact my answer is also legit in some way. I've spent quite some time with this issue, so a single up vote would make me happier...