# OSX: loadView doesn't execute

Tags: objective-c, macos, loadview

I've done some iOS coding but right now I'm trying to write a Mac App. This link: [viewDidLoad in NSViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422839/viewdidload-in-nsviewcontroller/5090825#5090825) says that the OSX equivalent of viewDidLoad is loadView. I want to call an initalizing method as soon as the view appears, but loadView doesn't seem to be executing; that is, the following code in my view controller:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    NSLog(@"Test");
    [self addPanGesture];
}
```

Doesn't seem to do anything. The NSLog never displays and the method addPanGesture never executes. Am I missing something really stupid or is loadView no longer the proper method to override?

EDIT: I switched to windowDidLoad and removed the super call per Ahmed Z's advice, but this doesn't work either. Do I have to do anything other than simply add the method like in iOS? Also, the link I orignially posted at the top seems to say in the "accepted" answer (not the highest rated one) that windowDidLoad is no longer used as of Mac OSX 10.5

EDIT 2: It also seems worth mentioning that I'm using a xib file. One stackoverflow link said that loadView was called only when programmatically setting up a view.

Comment: equivalent for viewDidLoad in osX is windowDidLoad not loadView.. Put your code in windowDidLoad and then try.

Comment: Still no luck. I have `- (void)windowDidLoad{ code }` is this right?

Comment: windowDidLoad is called on NSWindowController, not NSViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. By putting another NSWindow in my MainMenu.xib and creating a reference for it I was able to call

```
[self.secondWindow display];
```

to open a second window.